# Changing the boolean value on click

Tags: jquery, scope

I am trying to change the variable from false to true on click

```
var $popupStatus = false;

$('li a').click(function() {  
  console.log('The list item has been clicked'); // This console log is successful
  $popupStatus = true;
});

if($popupStatus) {
  console.log('The popup variable is true;'); // This console log doesn't show up
}
```

I know this must have something to do with scope but I can't see where I'm going wrong, thanks for the help.

Comment: The if condtion should be in a function of inside click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your scoping of the variable is correct, but to check the status on click, the `if()` condition should be in the handler or in a function; which would be called on click.
- If you simply add `if()` to `$(document).ready`, `$popupStauts` will always stay false.
- To verify the boolean change, you should check with `if()` on click or after the click handler works.

---

Try this.

```
var $popupStatus = false;

$('li a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('The list item has been clicked'); // This console log is successful
  $popupStatus = true;
  checkStatus();
});

function checkStatus(){
    if($popupStatus) {
       console.log('The popup variable is true;'); // This console log doesn't show up
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaAaz/)**

Comment: Thank you for this, still trying to learn when to use a function! All of these answers made a lot of sense I chose yours because it was the easiest for me to understand, thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$popupStatus` changes to `false` only when the click handler is executed which is not yet triggered as the js is parsed.

When it encounters `if()`, `$popupStatus` is still `false`, therefore `if` doesn't succeed.

Try triggering the event:

```
$('li a').click(function() {  
  console.log('The list item has been clicked'); // This console log is successful
  $popupStatus = true;
}).trigger('click');
```

Or put that `if` condition inside the handler based on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are evaluating `$popupStatus` variable only once - when the document has finished loading. You might want to move it to either the `click` handler or have a function that calls a function to check for the most recent value (see @shaunakde's solution).

**jQuery:**

```
var $popupStatus = false;

$('li').on('click', 'a', function() {

   $popupStatus = !($popupStatus); // This assigns $popupStatus an opposite value
   // $popupStatus = true; // Just sets $popupStatus to true

   alert($popupStatus);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y4Ep/)**